# dojo.tech C# examples not compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the dojo.tech C# examples to work and they are not compiling under visual studio 2022.

Tried googling some lines of code to see if I could figure which version of C#/.net but as of yet haven't figured it out.

Here is the code

```
  // read request body as a byte stream 
  using var streamReader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body);
  var body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

  // Get signature header value 
  if (HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(WebhookPayloadUtils.SignatureHeaderName, out var signatureHeader))
  {
    // use Dojo.Net SDK to deserialize and validate webhook payload
    var payload = WebhookPayloadUtils.ReadPayload(body, _webhookSecret, signatureHeader);

    // TODO: update your database or do some action based on successful payment 
  }
```

The example comes from
here https://github.com/dojo-engineering/dojo-samples/blob/main/webhooks/cs/verify-webhooks.cs

Dojo.techs webpage is here
https://docs.dojo.tech/docs/development-resources/webhooks

> Compiler errors include:
>
> CS1617 Invalid option '8.0' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2,
> Default or an integer in range 1 to 6.
>
> CS8370 Feature 'using declarations' is not available in C# 7.3. Please
> use language version 8.0 or greater.
>
> CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field,
> method, or property 'HttpContext.Request'
>
> CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
> Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing
> its return type to 'Task'.
>
> CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field,
> method, or property 'HttpContext.Request'

I'm using visual studio 2022 with the latest updates (Version 17.4.4). I've tried pasting into a webform project and .net core blazor. I do NuGet to get the Dojo.tech package that part seems to work ok. I can reduce compiler errors but I struggling to find the exact configuration they are using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is that the whole of your .cs file? I think that snippet is meant to be copied into an action method of a controller in a MVC project or similar. The controller will inherit a `HttpContext` property from its base class which will fix CS0120, and adding the `async` keyword to the method signature, e.g. `public async Task SomeMethod()` will fix CS4033.

Comment: That is the whole .cs file. As per the github link and webpages. Other examples are similar. I feel I'm missing some information from Dojo.tech or at least some critical details about the particular setup. They have been very sparse on the documentation. Your suggestion about the controller in a MVC project maybe the direction I need. I will look into that.

Comment: @Glenn Which of the five errors here are you confused? I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean, can you describe it more accurately?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT I had assumed I needed to configure visual studio differently such as a particular version of .Net or C# language.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to contact the developers. The code is abbreviated (not sure the reasoning). The code needs to be inserted into the controller section of MVC project.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: If you need to contact the developers use the discussion section on github https://github.com/orgs/dojo-engineering/discussions

Comment: And if you need to see a working C# example ignore the samples on the website and open this https://github.com/dojo-engineering/dojo-samples/tree/main/samples/accept-a-payment/prebuilt-checkout/server

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the reason of my previous comment was that people might have a similar problem and it would be helpful for them if you added more details to your answer. Offsite links may be useful now, but links get broken over time.